# flutter Hive with riverpod box getter always return null

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hive

I've make a singleton class as `Hive` initialization. But when I call the *getter* inside that class, it never return a value and returning an error instead. I've tried with `?` mark, it return `Null check operator used on a null value` when I call it wit `!` marks. Also tried with `late` and it give error `LateInitialization`.

```dart
class Takok {
  static final Takok _t = Takok._internal();
  factory Takok() => _t;

  Takok._internal();

  Box<Transaksi>? _boxTransaksi;
  Box<InappProses>? _boxInappProses;

  Future<Takok> akses() async {
    final takok = Takok._internal();
    final direktori = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    await Hive.initFlutter(direktori.path);
    await takok.init();

    return takok;
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    Hive.registerAdapter(TransaksiAdapter());
    Hive.registerAdapter(InappProsesAdapter());
    this._boxTransaksi = await Hive.openBox<Transaksi>('transaksi');
    this._boxInappProses = await Hive.openBox<InappProses>('inappproses');
  }

  Box<Transaksi> get boxTransaksi => _boxTransaksi!;
  Box<InappProses> get boxInappProses => _boxInappProses!;
}
```

When I try to check if the box is open on `main()` function, it returns true.

```dart
void main() async {
  await Takok().akses().then((value) {
    [value.boxTransaksi,value.boxInappProses].forEach((element) {
      if (element.isOpen) print('$element is open');
      });
    print('done checking');
  });
}
```

Anyone can help or explain to me how to fix this? I want to use inside a provider (*riverpod* exactly), like :

```dart
final providerTakok = Provider<Takok>((ref) => Takok());

final providerTakokHelper = ChangeNotifierProvider<TakokHelper>((ref) {
  final db = ref.read(providerTakok);
  final inapp = db.boxInappProses; // <-- this line which give the error
  return TakokHelper(db, inapp);
});
```

Then I consume above provider to another provider

```dart
final providerSplashskrin = Provider((ref) {
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 3),
    () async {
      try {
        final takokHelper = ref.watch(providerTakokHelper);
        print('objection'); // this line was printed if placed above takokHelper
        // ...
      } catch (e) {
        print('error: $e')
      }
    },
  );
});
```

And this is TakokHelper.dart

```dart
class TakokHelper extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Takok takok;
  final Box<InappProses> box;
  TakokHelper(this.takok, this.box)

  // ...
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that you cannot use `ref.watch` in callbacks. Try using `ref.read` or `ref.listen`.

As for the first part of your question, you can use `ProviderContainer` to load all your dependencies in it and pass such a container to `UncontrolledProviderScope`. Or override your provider after the value is loaded like this:

```
final storageProvider = Provider((_) => throw UnimplementedError); 

...

// main() async 

final storage = await Hive.initFlutter(direktori.path);

runApp(
  const ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      storageProvider.overrideWithValue(storage),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: the `storage` is a `void`, it can not be used as a value, I just try to modify `Takok` and the providers. I've change `watch()` to `read()` instead, but stil have the same error, which is Null checking

Answer (score 0):

After a last couple of days struggling and confused by my self, I finally fix the issue. The **Hive initialization** and **opening Hive box** must be in the same function. So in *Takok.dart* I merge the `akses()` and `init()`

Takok.dart

```dart
Future<Takok> akses() async {
  final takok = Takok._internal();
  final direktori = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(direktori.path);
    
  Hive.registerAdapter(TransaksiAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(InappProsesAdapter());
  this._boxTransaksi = await Hive.openBox<Transaksi>('transaksi');
  this._boxInappProses = await Hive.openBox<InappProses>('inappproses');

  return takok;
}
```